# XML formatting - select a subset of existing xml to create new one using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

My input XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.02">
    <BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn>
        <GrpHdr>
            <MsgId>FRDA000003421606</MsgId>
            <AddtlInf>BatchAccounting</AddtlInf>
        </GrpHdr>
        <Ntfctn>
            <Id>AC730486180000000002</Id>
            <ElctrncSeqNb>1234</ElctrncSeqNb>
            <Acct>
                <Svcr>
                    <FinInstnId>
                        <Othr>
                            <Id>40457258</Id>
                        </Othr>
                    </FinInstnId>
                </Svcr>
            </Acct>
            <Ntry>
                <Amt Ccy="EUR">126</Amt>
                <CdtDbtInd>CRDT</CdtDbtInd>
                <Sts>BOOK</Sts>
                <BkTxCd>
                    <Domn>
                        <Cd>PMNT</Cd>
                        <Fmly>
                            <Cd>RDDT</Cd>
                            <SubFmlyCd>ESDD</SubFmlyCd>
                        </Fmly>
                    </Domn>
                    <Prtry>
                        <Issr>SWIFT</Issr>
                    </Prtry>
                </BkTxCd>
                <AmtDtls>
                    <InstdAmt>
                        <Amt Ccy="EUR">126</Amt>
                        <CcyXchg/>
                    </InstdAmt>
                    <TxAmt>
                        <Amt Ccy="EUR">126</Amt>
                        <CcyXchg/>
                    </TxAmt>
                    <CntrValAmt>
                        <Amt Ccy="EUR">126</Amt>
                        <CcyXchg/>
                    </CntrValAmt>
                </AmtDtls>
                <Chrgs>
                    <TtlChrgsAndTaxAmt Ccy="AAA">0</TtlChrgsAndTaxAmt>
                    <Amt Ccy="AAA">0</Amt>
                    <CdtDbtInd>DBIT</CdtDbtInd>
                    <Tp>
                        <Cd>COMM</Cd>
                    </Tp>
                    <Rate>0</Rate>
                    <Br>SLEV</Br>
                    <Pty>
                        <FinInstnId>
                            <BIC>AAAAAA20</BIC>
                            <ClrSysMmbId>
                                <ClrSysId>
                                    <Cd>a</Cd>
                                </ClrSysId>
                                <MmbId>a</MmbId>
                            </ClrSysMmbId>
                            <Nm>a</Nm>
                            <PstlAdr>
                                <AdrTp>MLTO</AdrTp>
                                <Dept>a</Dept>
                                <SubDept>a</SubDept>
                                <StrtNm>a</StrtNm>
                                <BldgNb>a</BldgNb>
                                <PstCd>a</PstCd>
                                <TwnNm>a</TwnNm>
                                <CtrySubDvsn>a</CtrySubDvsn>
                                <Ctry>AA</Ctry>
                                <AdrLine>a</AdrLine>
                            </PstlAdr>
                            <Othr>
                                <Id>a</Id>
                                <SchmeNm>
                                    <Cd>a</Cd>
                                </SchmeNm>
                                <Issr>a</Issr>
                            </Othr>
                        </FinInstnId>
                        <BrnchId>
                            <Id>a</Id>
                            <Nm>a</Nm>
                            <PstlAdr>
                                <AdrTp>ADDR</AdrTp>
                                <Dept>a</Dept>
                                <SubDept>a</SubDept>
                                <StrtNm>a</StrtNm>
                                <BldgNb>a</BldgNb>
                                <PstCd>a</PstCd>
                                <TwnNm>a</TwnNm>
                                <CtrySubDvsn>a</CtrySubDvsn>
                                <Ctry>AA</Ctry>
                                <AdrLine>a</AdrLine>
                            </PstlAdr>
                        </BrnchId>
                    </Pty>
                    <Tax>
                        <Id>a</Id>
                        <Rate>0</Rate>
                        <Amt Ccy="AAA">0</Amt>
                    </Tax>
                </Chrgs>
                <NtryDtls>
                    <Btch>
                        <MsgId>FG00000000000y88sd</MsgId>
                        <NbOfTxs>2</NbOfTxs>
                    </Btch>
                    <TxDtls>
                        <Refs>
                            <AcctSvcrRef>FRDA00000342</AcctSvcrRef>
                            <EndToEndId>E2E220161205123001</EndToEndId>
                            <TxId>FRDA00004341</TxId>
                            <MndtId>MANsecT1COR1201006</MndtId>
                        </Refs>
                        <AmtDtls/>
                        <Chrgs>
                            <TtlChrgsAndTaxAmt Ccy="BBB">0</TtlChrgsAndTaxAmt>
                            <Amt Ccy="BBB">0</Amt>
                            <CdtDbtInd>DBIT</CdtDbtInd>
                            <Tp>
                                <Cd>COMM</Cd>
                            </Tp>
                            <Rate>0</Rate>
                            <Br>SLEV</Br>
                            <Pty>
                                <FinInstnId>
                                    <BIC>BBBBB20</BIC>
                                    <ClrSysMmbId>
                                        <ClrSysId>
                                            <Cd>b</Cd>
                                        </ClrSysId>
                                        <MmbId>b</MmbId>
                                    </ClrSysMmbId>
                                    <Nm>b</Nm>
                                    <PstlAdr>
                                        <AdrTp>MLTO</AdrTp>
                                        <Dept>b</Dept>
                                        <SubDept>b</SubDept>
                                        <StrtNm>b</StrtNm>
                                        <BldgNb>b</BldgNb>
                                        <PstCd>b</PstCd>
                                        <TwnNm>b</TwnNm>
                                        <CtrySubDvsn>b</CtrySubDvsn>
                                        <Ctry>BB</Ctry>
                                        <AdrLine>b</AdrLine>
                                    </PstlAdr>
                                    <Othr>
                                        <Id>b</Id>
                                        <SchmeNm>
                                            <Cd>b</Cd>
                                        </SchmeNm>
                                        <Issr>b</Issr>
                                    </Othr>
                                </FinInstnId>
                                <BrnchId>
                                    <Id>b</Id>
                                    <Nm>b</Nm>
                                    <PstlAdr>
                                        <AdrTp>bDDR</AdrTp>
                                        <Dept>b</Dept>
                                        <SubDept>b</SubDept>
                                        <StrtNm>b</StrtNm>
                                        <BldgNb>b</BldgNb>
                                        <PstCd>b</PstCd>
                                        <TwnNm>b</TwnNm>
                                        <CtrySubDvsn>b</CtrySubDvsn>
                                        <Ctry>BB</Ctry>
                                        <AdrLine>b</AdrLine>
                                    </PstlAdr>
                                </BrnchId>
                            </Pty>
                            <Tax>
                                <Id>b</Id>
                                <Rate>0</Rate>
                                <Amt Ccy="BBB">0</Amt>
                            </Tax>
                        </Chrgs>
                        <RltdPties>
                            <Cdtr>
                                <Nm>Creditor 1</Nm>
                                <PstlAdr>
                                    <Ctry>PT</Ctry>
                                    <AdrLine>TEST TEST</AdrLine>
                                    <AdrLine>TEST TEST</AdrLine>
                                </PstlAdr>
                                <CtryOfRes>PT</CtryOfRes>
                            </Cdtr>
                            <CdtrAcct>
                                <Id>
                                    <IBAN>FR7630588000010050000143176</IBAN>
                                </Id>
                            </CdtrAcct>
                        </RltdPties>
                        <RltdDts>
                            <AccptncDtTm>2016-12-06T04:01:10</AccptncDtTm>
                            <IntrBkSttlmDt>2016-12-07</IntrBkSttlmDt>
                        </RltdDts>
                        <AddtlTxInf/>
                    </TxDtls>
                    <TxDtls>
                        <Refs>
                            <AcctSvcrRef>FRDA00000343</AcctSvcrRef>
                            <EndToEndId>E2E120161205123003</EndToEndId>
                            <TxId>FRDA00003343</TxId>
                            <MndtId>MANFRST1COR1201003</MndtId>
                        </Refs>
                        <AmtDtls/>
                        <RltdPties>
                            <Cdtr>
                                <Nm>Creditor 1</Nm>
                                <PstlAdr>
                                    <Ctry>PT</Ctry>
                                    <AdrLine>TEST TEST</AdrLine>
                                    <AdrLine>TEST TEST</AdrLine>
                                </PstlAdr>
                                <CtryOfRes>PT</CtryOfRes>
                            </Cdtr>
                            <CdtrAcct>
                                <Id>
                                    <IBAN>FR7630588000010050000143176</IBAN>
                                </Id>
                            </CdtrAcct>
                        </RltdPties>
                        <RltdDts>
                            <AccptncDtTm>2016-12-06T04:01:10</AccptncDtTm>
                            <IntrBkSttlmDt>2016-12-07</IntrBkSttlmDt>
                        </RltdDts>
                        <AddtlTxInf/>
                    </TxDtls>
                </NtryDtls>
                <AddtlNtryInf>ENRICHED|TRUE SETT_METHOD|SEPA IAT_IND|FALSE DOMESTIC_IND|FALSE PRIORITY_IND|FALSE</AddtlNtryInf>
            </Ntry>
        </Ntfctn>
    </BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn>
</Document>
```

I want extract a subset from this XML and my expected output should look like:

```
<TxDtls>
    <Refs>
        <AcctSvcrRef>FRDA00000342</AcctSvcrRef>
        <EndToEndId>E2E220161205123001</EndToEndId>
        <TxId>FRDA00004341</TxId>
        <MndtId>MANsecT1COR1201006</MndtId>
    </Refs>
    <AmtDtls/>
    <Chrgs>
        <TtlChrgsAndTaxAmt Ccy="BBB">0</TtlChrgsAndTaxAmt>
        <Amt Ccy="BBB">0</Amt>
        <CdtDbtInd>DBIT</CdtDbtInd>
        <Tp>
            <Cd>COMM</Cd>
        </Tp>
        <Rate>0</Rate>
        <Br>SLEV</Br>
        <Pty>
            <FinInstnId>
                <BIC>BBBBB20</BIC>
                <ClrSysMmbId>
                    <ClrSysId>
                        <Cd>b</Cd>
                    </ClrSysId>
                    <MmbId>b</MmbId>
                </ClrSysMmbId>
                <Nm>b</Nm>
                <PstlAdr>
                    <AdrTp>MLTO</AdrTp>
                    <Dept>b</Dept>
                    <SubDept>b</SubDept>
                    <StrtNm>b</StrtNm>
                    <BldgNb>b</BldgNb>
                    <PstCd>b</PstCd>
                    <TwnNm>b</TwnNm>
                    <CtrySubDvsn>b</CtrySubDvsn>
                    <Ctry>BB</Ctry>
                    <AdrLine>b</AdrLine>
                </PstlAdr>
                <Othr>
                    <Id>b</Id>
                    <SchmeNm>
                        <Cd>b</Cd>
                    </SchmeNm>
                    <Issr>b</Issr>
                </Othr>
            </FinInstnId>
            <BrnchId>
                <Id>b</Id>
                <Nm>b</Nm>
                <PstlAdr>
                    <AdrTp>bDDR</AdrTp>
                    <Dept>b</Dept>
                    <SubDept>b</SubDept>
                    <StrtNm>b</StrtNm>
                    <BldgNb>b</BldgNb>
                    <PstCd>b</PstCd>
                    <TwnNm>b</TwnNm>
                    <CtrySubDvsn>b</CtrySubDvsn>
                    <Ctry>BB</Ctry>
                    <AdrLine>b</AdrLine>
                </PstlAdr>
            </BrnchId>
        </Pty>
        <Tax>
            <Id>b</Id>
            <Rate>0</Rate>
            <Amt Ccy="BBB">0</Amt>
        </Tax>
    </Chrgs>
    <RltdPties>
        <Cdtr>
            <Nm>Creditor 1</Nm>
            <PstlAdr>
                <Ctry>PT</Ctry>
                <AdrLine>TEST TEST</AdrLine>
                <AdrLine>TEST TEST</AdrLine>
            </PstlAdr>
            <CtryOfRes>PT</CtryOfRes>
        </Cdtr>
        <CdtrAcct>
            <Id>
                <IBAN>FR7630588000010050000143176</IBAN>
            </Id>
        </CdtrAcct>
    </RltdPties>
    <RltdDts>
        <AccptncDtTm>2016-12-06T04:01:10</AccptncDtTm>
        <IntrBkSttlmDt>2016-12-07</IntrBkSttlmDt>
    </RltdDts>
    <AddtlTxInf/>
</TxDtls>
<TxDtls>
    <Refs>
        <AcctSvcrRef>FRDA00000343</AcctSvcrRef>
        <EndToEndId>E2E120161205123003</EndToEndId>
        <TxId>FRDA00003343</TxId>
        <MndtId>MANFRST1COR1201003</MndtId>
    </Refs>
    <AmtDtls/>
    <RltdPties>
        <Cdtr>
            <Nm>Creditor 1</Nm>
            <PstlAdr>
                <Ctry>PT</Ctry>
                <AdrLine>TEST TEST</AdrLine>
                <AdrLine>TEST TEST</AdrLine>
            </PstlAdr>
            <CtryOfRes>PT</CtryOfRes>
        </Cdtr>
        <CdtrAcct>
            <Id>
                <IBAN>FR7630588000010050000143176</IBAN>
            </Id>
        </CdtrAcct>
    </RltdPties>
    <RltdDts>
        <AccptncDtTm>2016-12-06T04:01:10</AccptncDtTm>
        <IntrBkSttlmDt>2016-12-07</IntrBkSttlmDt>
    </RltdDts>
    <AddtlTxInf/>
</TxDtls>
```

I am able to achieve this using the XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:od="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.02" exclude-result-prefixes="od xsi">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="od:*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="TransactionDetails">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="od:Document/od:BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn/od:Ntfctn/od:Ntry/od:NtryDtls/od:TxDtls">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But in addition to this, the requirement is to replace

```
"od:Document/od:BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn/od:Ntfctn/od:Ntry/od:NtryDtls/od:TxDtls/od:Chrgs"
```

with

```
od:Document/od:BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn/od:Ntfctn/od:Ntry/od:Chrgs
```

when

```
od:Document/od:BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn/od:Ntfctn/od:Ntry/od:AddtlNtryInf
```

contains the text "ENRICHED" and

```
od:Document/od:BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn/od:Ntfctn/od:Ntry/od:NtryDtls/od:Btch
```

is present

So basically I am looking to achieve following

```
When input xml element = od:Document/od:BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn/od:Ntfctn/od:Ntry/od:NtryDtls/od:TxDtls
  Start copying the child tags
  While copying the tags, if element = od:Document/od:BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn/od:Ntfctn/od:Ntry/od:NtryDtls/od:TxDtls/od:Chrgs
   if "od:Document/od:BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn/od:Ntfctn/od:Ntry/od:AddtlNtryInf" contains'ENRICHED' and "od:Document/od:BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn/od:Ntfctn/od:Ntry/od:NtryDtls/od:Btch" is present
   Copy all elements under "od:Document/od:BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn/od:Ntfctn/od:Ntry/od:Chrgs"
  else
   Copy all elements under "od:Document/od:BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn/od:Ntfctn/od:Ntry/od:NtryDtls/od:TxDtls/od:Chrgs"
```

Need help in solving this. It may be simple but I am new to XML.

Thanks in advance

(Let me know if you require further information from my end)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be better to start with the Identity Template to handle copying existing nodes, rather than using `xsl:copy-of`

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, if you only want to extract `od:TxDtls` nodes, you would have to explicitly select it, to ignore the nodes you don't want.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="od:Document/od:BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn/od:Ntfctn/od:Ntry/od:NtryDtls/od:TxDtls" />
</xsl:template>
```

In terms of your logic, you then only need a template in the case where you do want to copy the `Chrgs` from elsewhere (i.e. where `AddtlNtryInf` contains "ENRICHED" and `Btch` is present), as the identity template will already cover the "else" condition.

```
<xsl:template match="od:TxDtls/od:Chrgs[contains(../../../od:AddtlNtryInf, 'ENRICHED') and  ../../od:Btch]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="../../../od:Chrgs" />
</xsl:template>
```

So, the template match contains the condition you want to check, and if they are try it will copy the `Chrgs` from elsewhere.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:od="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.02" exclude-result-prefixes="od">
    <xsl:output method="xml"  indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="od:Document/od:BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn/od:Ntfctn/od:Ntry/od:NtryDtls/od:TxDtls" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="od:TxDtls/od:Chrgs[contains(../../../od:AddtlNtryInf, 'ENRICHED') and  ../../od:Btch]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../../../od:Chrgs" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT** - If you also want the elements in the output XML to be in no namespace (as opposed to being in namespace 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.02' as per the input), add this template to the XSLT to override the identity template, and output new elements in no namespace instead.

```
<xsl:template match="*" priority="2">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I am getting following output

Comment: thanks for the quick reply and help. I am getting a output close to my  requirement. but the output has <TxDtls xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.02"> from which I want o remove the xmlns completely. Can u suggest what can be done for this

Comment: thanks for the quick reply and help. I am getting a output close to my requirement. but the output has <TxDtls xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.02"> from which I want o remove the xmlns completely. Can u suggest what can be done for this

Comment: I've made an edit to my answer to show how you can remove the namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sorry to bother you, but there is change in requirement and I want to extract individual child element under "TxDtls" so the output should look like <Refs>all child under Refs</Refs>delimiter<RltdPties>all child nodes </RltdPties>delimiter<Refs>all child nodes</Refs>delimiter<RltdPties>all child nodes</RltdPties> We are basically sending this output to some other interface wherein it will be delimited based on the delimiter and the tags would be used to form the desired xml. Any suggestions on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: This may not be sounding as a normal way to use XML and XSLT but we are using XML to communicate between a legacy system and a newer system. The XML would be coming form newer system broken into parts and send to Legacy system to create the final output. Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried to modify your XSLT as per my new requirements but the output I am getting is, <Refs>all child nodes</Refs><Refs>all child nodes</Refs><RltdPties>all child nodes</RltdPties><RltdPties>All child nodes</RltdPties>. This happens when TxDtls occur multiple times. I want the output as <Refs>all child under</Refs>delimiter<RltdPties>all child nodes </RltdPties>delimiter<Refs>all child nodes</Refs>delimiter<RltdPties>all child nodes</RltdPties>

Comment: If you have a new requirement then it is probably best to ask a new question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Will post a new question. I am new to the forum too so was not aware of how things work around here. Its good to get input from someone as experience as you. Once again thanks a lot for your help and guidance.

Comment: I have posted a new question "Extracting child nodes from a single parent using XSLT and reformatting"